# Docking Port Bug

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've been working on a space station and, upon sending up the final module and getting it in place I realized I neglected to send up the "hallways" that connect them (the modules) to the core. I docked it elsewhere to wait until I sent them up. Upon docking the hallways to the core, I realized only one of the two ports had actually connected. I decided I would just dock the module to the hallways and proceed to undock the hallways and module from the core and correct it so both would be attached.

I managed to undock and then redock it, but after checking I found that once again only one of the two ports had connected. I tried again, but now neither ports are docking. I have seen mention of docking bugs in previous versions but none that fit my issue.

I have attempted backing up further before attempting to redock, loading, saving and loading, and restating the game. All to no avail.

Is there a way to fix the issue without having to send up a new core and another of the other module?

Below is a picture of the uncooperative docking ports.

[image]

Comment: There is so much wrong happening in this image.  The quad-couplers are maybe acceptable if you absolutely need perfect alignment, but you should only be using double-couplers when the sub-assemblies are identical.  That is not the case here.  In addition, you're further complicating things by having another piece between the two main sections.

Answer (score 2):

1. In-Universe fix: Get [KIS](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/101928-105-kerbal-inventory-system-kis-125/)/[KAS](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/83468-105-kerbal-attachment-system-kas-055/) and send Engineer in a shuttle to fix it. You can strut it together on EVA or remove/replace/add parts as you see fit. You can even use explosives if you are angry enough. It is wildcard fix for all other issues as well. (Heck, you can even build cube-sats in orbit with it ;)
2. Out-of-Universe fix: Check docking port `state` in save file, `Acquired` state on port might prevent it from docking (bug). Changing it back to `Ready` should fix it. Example of this operation can be found in famous [Duna, Ore Bust!](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/110096-duna-ore-bust-a-ksp-graphic-novel-complete/#comment-1949048)

If you have problems to find part entry in save file, which is very probable as it is big and ugly, try following check-list:

1. Backup previous saves for safety.
2. Start new empty test game and launch your module (just put it on launchpad).
3. Save your test game and use its file for reference.
4. Find broken ship in save.
5. Heal it with content from test save.

Note: do not use `quicksave.sfs` for manual repairs as game can overwrite it suddenly. Other than that, it is safe to perform repairs with game running in background.

Example of reinforcing structure with KAS/KIS:

[image: loaded]

Rover loaded to cargo bay, however without any safety locks it will be destroyed during takeoff. Fuel pipe will be used first as it will merge ships into single entity (for some reason struts can't do that). Then struts will secure rover in place.

[image: lockandloaded]

After mounting hard points on cargo bay wall and on rover itself Kerbal can connect them with pipes and struts.

[image: away]

Liftoff!

Cargo plane and KAS/KIS rover added to my [SE.Gaming KSP repository](http://1drv.ms/1Qng86h)

Comment: How to add party like struts to allready launched vehicles?

Comment: @Zaibis It is feature of KAS/KIS mods, they have special strut and fuel line  to mount on EVA. I can add some screenshots later today.

Comment: @Zaibis I added some screenshots