# Docking ports are not snapping

Tags: kerbal-space-program

[image: Docking ports are close enough]

Why could two docking ports to not snap to each other? They a definitely close enough, speed is about 0.5 m/s and both ships have power. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Interesting question! At that speed + from that distance, they should be glued by now.

Comment: Just to be sure. are ports enabled? Have you tried other docking ports on that orange tank and/or solution from [Docking Port Bug question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258782/docking-port-bug) ?

Comment: @PTwr I double checked that, everything is enabled. I tried other ports, without any success. Restarting same(!) mission from the launchpad solved problem. Must be some bug.

Comment: That would be bugged "state" then, happens way too often, I wrote how to fix it in linked question. Its useful knowledge when building space station in KSP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the ports are parallel to each other, their angle looks slightly off. Moving your ship sideways will help with getting the right angle.

Answer (score 1):

The angle in the picture seems quite within norm for Clamp-o-tron standard. The Sr. ports are more sensitive about it (and Jr. - less.). The problem is that the game sometimes fails to notice ports are in position - a rather rare bug. You may need to repeat the approach - or save, quit, restart and load again.

Also, the "top" node on both ports needs to be empty. If you attached something to the port's top node, even if you moved it using the translation gizmo somewhere else, the node is still occupied and the port won't engage. Rightclick ports, "decouple node".

Also, if you *just* undocked, the port won't re-engage until you moved at least ~3m away from it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that helped me a lot, was to use the [Docking Port Alignment Indicator](https://mods.curse.com/ksp-mods/kerbal/220299-docking-port-alignment-indicator-version-6-5-2) mod.

[image]

Essentially, you set your docking port with "control from here" and then set the target's docking port with "set as target."  Then the indicators help you reduce your alignment angles to zero.

Here is [a link to the tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKjWUInZ0g4).

Playing with this mod helped me learn how to get the hang of docking, so much so that I don't *need* to install the mod any more.

Comment: If we talk about mods, I like to fly with Docking Helper backplate lights from [MRS](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/83959-12-modular-rocket-systems-v1131-2016-10-21-stock-alike-parts-pack/), much cleaner solution than bunch of spotlights.